Can javascript have race condition?
For the following code in javascript I want to know if there are concurrent api requests to increment count is there any possibility of a race condition considering the fact that javascript is single threaded.
  app.post('/increment', async (req, res) => {
    await someAsyncFunction(); // Asynchronous operation
    count++; // Increment operation
    res.send('Count incremented');
  });

From what I understand there shouldn't be any as once the execution resumes after await someAsyncFunction() count++ being synchronous should be executed in one stretch for a request before the execution resumes the increment for other requests. Let me know if I am wrong to understand this.

you haven't really shown enough about how count is used - how can there be a race condition on a variable that is used in one single line of code?

I understand that this is not a practical situation. This is more of a theoretical question on how javascript works. I asked the same question to ChatGPT and its response was there would be a race condition. But I didn't feel like that was reliable answer.

If you ask chatGPT anything about programming you'll be lucky to get a reliable answer

Hope it gets better. So for my question I take the answer as no, there would not be any race condition

anything that happens in the asyncFunction that is dependant on the request can create a scneario where a request that was sent after a certain request will increment the count before

Yes, JavaScript can experience race conditions, especially in environments where asynchronous code execution is involved, such as with promises, callbacks, or web APIs like setTimeout, fetch, or event listeners.

Thanks for the response but can you please put an answer which is specific to the question.

An example perhaps so you answer is complete
